# Method with multiple inputs java

Tags: java, interface

I have a interface and in the interface I want to declare a method such that it can take any number of objects as input.

Something like this:

```
interface Implementable{
     public ReturnObj doIt(objects ....);
}
```

Please advise

Comment: `public ReturnObj doIt(Object... o);` should work. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs

Comment: @aioobe: That's a nice edit :D "want to"

Comment: I did not complete my question.without checking I pressed the button.
I was about to ask the difference between varargs and passing an array, I got the answer... Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax would in your case be:

```
interface Implementable{
    public ReturnObj doIt(Object... objs);
}
```

Official documentation for var-arg methods is found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

> ***I was about to ask the difference between varargs and passing an array,***

Varargs gets compiled into an argument of an array-type. The only difference is with the vararg syntax, method calls such as

```
doIt("hello", "world");
```

will be compiled into

```
doIt(new Object[] { "hello", "world" });
```

In other words, given a declaration such as

```
public ReturnObj doIt(Object[] objs);
```

you'll have

```
doIt(new Object[] { "hello", "world" });  // works fine
doIt("hello", "world");                   // won't compile
```

while given the var-arg declaration, both method calls will compile and be equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Pass an array:

```
public ReturnObj doIt(Object[] input);
```

or use the equivalent varargs expression

```
public ReturnObj doIt(Object... input);
```

Comment: uhm, I wouldn't go as far as saying that they are equivalent.

Comment: @aioobe - let's say: in this simple example, they are. langspec *If the last formal parameter is a variable arity parameter of type T, it is considered to define a formal parameter of type T[]*

Comment: True, but in the presense of a method call, such as `o.doIt()` one works, the other doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to understand [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) first.
2. What is the question?

Example:

```
interface Implementable{
    public ReturnObj doIt(Object... object);
}
```

Alternatively (which I should prefer, especially in Web Services design):

```
interface Implementable{
    public ReturnObj doIt(Object[] object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to ask a question, but assuming you want to know how to declare a method which takes variable number of arguments, check out this link:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

So it would be

```
interface Implementable{

         public ReturnObj doIt(Object... objects);
}
```